# How fix width or/and height of a custom UI element in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, custom-controls

I want to create custom UI Element as in [Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html), and now has a question.

Can I fix width or/and height of my element as in UIActivityIndicator, UISearchBar etc as in picture:

[image: fixed size]?

I tried this:

```
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
```

Custom view height got height only when I added constraints.
Height in properties window didn't fixed.
And also constraints conflict appears when I set height constraint in interface builder. This conflict does not appears when I does not change `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property, but other troubles remains.